# Neuroph Studio: train, stop, pause and test button disabled

Tags: neural-network

I have installed NeurophStudio 2.91 for Windows. I have created a Neural Network using Multilayer Perceptron and loaded some training data. Now I`d like to train the Neural Network, but the buttons train, stop, pause and test are disabled. How can I enable them? I also had the problem that the program does not react several times and I had to restart it. Installing it new did not help.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but I was struggling with the same this morning. Turned out that you have to drag the training set from the files pane, and drop it on the top-most layer of the NN (input layer). Once you do that, the train, stop, test input buttons become enabled. Consult http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/MultiLayerPerceptron.html for more info.

Have only been using Neuroph for a few hours, and it was so erratic that it drove me crazy. But I realized that once you understand how things work, it'll work as expected most of the times. For an example, if you run a training session where your network architecture and training set are such that the training might never converge, and you haven't set a max iterations limit, then it'll keep training forever. Many of the times the graphs aren't showing properly in real-time, so you'd never know that the training is still going on, but it'll slow down your machine to a crawl.

Didn't find 'enough' material for a complete newb to get going, and I'm still struggling with some very basic stuff (like how to reset a Neural Network from the studio), but it seems worth it to plough through the initial stumbles just for the sake of having a tool to design/train/troubleshoot your NN in a gui and then export it to your app, alone.

Answer (score 0):

i also face your problem a hours ago, and that was cus of its version i was using 2.93 then i uninstall it and i install 2.8 and i work perfectly for me

hope this will help u!!!